# Find the CN and time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

Through my study for the recurrences I was trying to solve this recurrence
can you check it for me

```
public static int java(int N) {
  if (N == 1) 
    return 1; 
  return (java(N/2) + java(N/2)); 
}
```

I think this is the equation

```
C(1) = 1
CN = 2CN/2 + 1
```

and the complexity is O(log N)

can you check it for me

Comment: This looks good and correct.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful can you tell me where did you get the n

Comment: @Mira - I am, nowadays, not under my control. Don't know what is happening with me, I am sorry. It has to be O(log n).

Comment: @YoungHobbit - See my above comment. BTW, upvoted your answer too.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful no worries thank you so much for your help and fast replies :)

Comment: Just a FYI, because many time I see that new users do not do this [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int java(int N) {
  if (N == 1) 
    return 1; 
  return 2 * java(N/2); 
}
```

Instead of calling the same twice, just multiply it by 2. There is not need to calculate it again for the same input.

Complexity is `O(log N)`, because you are dividing the problem by factor of `2` every time.